# Sending mail (in Localhost) with CodeIgniter email() library from gmail does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I have set the codeIgniter email() to send email from my Google Account, but it errors. It does not work, it says it cannot connect to the server or that the server party does not respond.

I have enabled (uncommented) these extensions in php.ini:

```
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Here is my CI configurations:

```
$configs = array(
        'protocol'=>'smtp',
        'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_user'=>'cgmaster.iran@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass'=>"PASSWORD",
        'smtp_port'=>'456'
        );
        $this->load->library("email", $configs);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->to("mostafatalebi@rocketmail.com");
        $this->email->from("cgmaster.iran@gmail.com", "Mostafa Talebi");
        $this->email->subject("This is bloody amazing.");
        $this->email->message("Body of the Message");
        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "Done!";   
        }
        else
        {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();    
        }
```

And here is the first line of the Error that I am getting:

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of CI are you using? If it's 2.1.4 then there is a discrepancy in your config array. Try this:

```
$configs = array(
    'protocol'  =>  'smtp',
    'smtp_host' =>  'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_user' =>  'cgmaster.iran@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' =>  'PASSWORD',
    'smtp_port' =>  '465'
);
```

Comment: Your gmail smtp port was wrong, also config key is not 'smtp_password' it's 'smtp_pass' (I think you've updated your question and fixed the latter)