# Getting Error on Sending Email - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have the below code for sending email, and on this I am getting `SMTP error`.

> The following `SMTP error` was encountered: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> Unable to send data: **AUTH LOGIN**

It is a very long error I have just provided the upper part.

`CODE`.

```
$frommail            = "sharadrsoni@gmail.com";
$config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'sharadrsoni@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'pass'; //your smtp password
$config['mailtype']  = 'html';
$config['charset']   = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap']  = TRUE;
$config['newline']   = "\r\n";

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($frommail, $companyfullname);
$this->email->to($tomail);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->set_mailtype('html');
$this->email->message($MHtml);

$emailSent = $this->email->send();
```

I have tried couple of ways but ended showing this error only.

I am using `CodeIgniter` `version`: `2.1.0`

Comment: Reference :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647386/sending-mail-in-localhost-with-codeigniter-email-library-from-gmail-does-not

Comment: I have already seen this post, the changes that were suggested are already done. Kindly have a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Comment: Please try with  $config['smtp_port']=587 $config['smtp_secure']='tls'

Comment: Have you tried using a different port? It may influence.. In mine, I use `$config['smtp_port'] = 25`,  although I use a different email library

Comment: Also don't use single quotes on the port number, it's not necessary and may influence the result (I'm not sure, cause I never tried it)

Comment: Have you enable extension php_openssl.dll in your php.ini file ?

Comment: @ShashankShah - Yes its enabled.

Comment: in-case if you have just enabled them server needs to get restart by service apache2 restart

Comment: @JuOliveira, I tried using 25 as port and also wrote without quotes but no luck :(

Comment: @ShashankShah I have done it already all this, before posting this question.

Comment: @ShashankShah Now I will try with TLS as you suggested.

Comment: ok it worked ??

Comment: @ShashankShah I am working on it.

Comment: you can use swift mailer in codeigniter . if you want to use swift mailer then tell me i will give you code.